# This song'll have you in a spin

Tags: word, cipher

My friend wanted me to listen to a song, but unfortunately all he told me was this

> 01111000 01101001 01100111 01111000 01111010 01110110 01111001 01101111 01111010

He loves playing Clash of Clans so maybe that has something to do with it...

Hint:

> The binary is supposed to be a string, not numbers!

Comment: If we think of these as binary, then these convert to: xigxzvyoz

Comment: @AggieKidd how did it became xigxvyoz?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL By converting each binary string to decimal, and then each decimal to a character. (http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-ascii-text-converter)

Comment: @AggieKidd I was thinking of converting them to decimal and linking them with troop cost.

Comment: I don't play the game Clash of Clans, but I think it could be something related to the character/maps or something that has 8 different *bits*. It would be pointless to mention that if its just a classic binary puzzle.

Comment: His favourite party game is twister too

Comment: Does this require knowledge of Clash of Clans to solve?

Comment: @f'' it does not require knowledge of anything IN the game, I myself have not played it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Samsung2710](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20619/samsung2710) has already converted the binary to

> xigxzvyoz

Now by using Vigenère Cipher with the key

> **supercell**, (the company who made Clash of Clans)

we get

> fortitudo

and by little google search I get some **wrong answers**

> 1. [Veritas et Fortitudo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq_7A7PV8u4)
> 2. [Lesiëm - Fortitudo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfS9epJW4ZA)
> 3. [Wildbirds & Peacedrums - Peeling Off The Layers (Fortitude title music)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzfg8ziVInI)

But the **right answer** is maybe bit more complex to find

> Fortitude means bravery. And a band named '[Supercell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercell_(band))' had a song named **[The Bravery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onVjiCfi0wQ)** in the album ' Zigaexperientia'

*Thanks to @ffao for help. :)*

Comment: This is VERY close, those songs are not the correct ones, *maybe the cipher key is used for more than just being the key*.... ;)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre It doesn't ring a bell. But I found another song by Wildbirds & Peacedrums. Is it what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is one last step before the song can be found, not quite decrypting as such though

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre, translating?

Comment: That's how I would interpret "not quite decrypting" :)

Comment: I suppose only people like those terrible weeaboos with anime avatars would immediately recognize that the key is also a band name ;)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Edited...i hope it is the one

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping my avatar might give something away as they are a Japanese band, and The Bravery is a song used in an anime ;)

Comment: By the way the supercell key was also hinted at by the comment saying about *Twister* and also the title of the riddle!

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I didn't know that there is a tornado by that name. lol..I guessed the key in one go bcz I play that game too and I have to look at that name when the game starts :p The guess of the key was also because of the number of letters of the string and your comment that it wasn't related to the gameplay of clash of clans.

Comment: Well done then! I just realised the irony of the comment @ffao made after clicking on their profile, well played

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, if you convert the binary into ASCII, you get

> xigxzvyoz.

As "cipher" is tagged in the post, I used a substitution cipher solver to see what words this could be substituted in. I got

> ABRASIONS, ABRASIVES, EXTENSION, GANGSTERS, HYPHENATE, and PAUPERIZE

as my answers. Could "gangsters" be a topic of the song? This is a bit of a stretch, however.

Comment: Unfortunately not, good try though, it's another type of cypher!

Comment: Can you tell me if the binary conversion step is on the right track?

Comment: Yes that is the correct binary translation :)